# RStudioで文字化けして表示されるエラーを直したい

Tags: r

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ファイルを保存するときやコードを書いているときにこの表示がでます。どうすればよいでしょうか？

WindowsでRは3.3.4です。RStudioが実行環境です！

Comment: 「どんな操作をした時か」「OSの種類やバージョン」など、もう少し具体的な情報を追記できませんか？文字化けが問題なのか、エラーが出ること自体が問題なのかもこの説明だけでは第三者からは分かりません。

Comment: ファイルを保存するときやコードを書いているときにこの表示がでます。WindowsでRは3.3.4です。エラーがでることを直してほしいです。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/122627

Answer (score 3):

そのファイルを他のテキストエディタで開いているとか、あるいは書き込みの権限がないファイルを修正して保存しようとしていないでしょうか？

Windows上のRStudioだと文字化けしてしまいますが、他のテキストエディタで開いているファイルをRStudioで保存させようとして同じエラーメッセージを出せたので、上記のような理由ではないかと思います。

Comment: 他のテキストエディタで開いているわけでも、書き込み権限がないファイルを修正しているわけでもありませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

作業中のRスクリプトがあるフォルダに、以下のような名前のファイル、フォルダがありますか？
※Windowsの設定で「隠しファイル、隠しフォルダーを表示する」が有効になっている必要があります。

- (フォルダ名).Rproj
- .Rproj.user

よくわからなければ、Rのプロンプトに

dir(all.files = TRUE)

と入力し、出てきた結果をこちらに貼り付けてください（個人情報や機密が含まれるような記述は削除してください）。

もしこれらがあるようでしたら、RStudioをいったん終了し、上記2つのファイル、フォルダーをデスクトップなど別の場所に移動させてください。そのうえで、再度RスクリプトをRStudioで開くと、エラーメッセージが出なくなるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

他のテキストエディタで開いているわけではないとのことでしたが、ワーキングディレクトリがGoogleドライブなどのオンライストレージとローカルが同期するように設定されてはいないでしょうか？

自分の環境で、Googleドライブと同期しているフォルダをワーキングディレクトリとしていて、.Rmdや.Rを書いていると同様のエラーが散発し、同期をやめたらエラーが出なくなりました。
オンライストレージの仕様によるかと思いますがおそらく、オンライストレージのクライントが同期のためファイルを参照しているとき（それも一時ファイルにちょっとした変更があるたびなので頻繁）にエラーが出るのではないかと思います。